# Under what condition does the AI share an intrigue with you?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

So King Kamehameha just warned me that he is spying on Attila the Hun and that Attina is planning to backstab me with his fleet. Very cool. I also share intrigue with AI civs when I want to increase my reputation with them, but my question is, **how does the AI decide whether to share an intrigue with a human player?**

e.g. do they always share an intrigue? Or do they only share it if you are "friendly" with them? Or only if it serves their purpose?

What I'm trying to understand is what I have to do in order to make sure I'm being informed of these plots against me.

Comment: So far I have only seen this when I had a declaration of friendship with the civ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AI civs will only intrigue you if you are friends with them, ("freindly") you need to have a good relationship with the civ past friendly however, I have only ever had it happen when I was friends, and not all civs will share information like this, its based on their personality