# Does the AI have a mechanism to know somebody engineered a war against it?

Tags: civilization-5

Let me summarise a game so far for you: playing Morocco King Continent

It was very peaceful continent on my side. 
Everyone shook hands and there were no wars, a lot of research agreement and stuff.
Venice is mostly friendly with me. We made a lot of Declaration of Friendships from time to time. The only red incident was when my spy was caught once, from this point onwards I didn't spy on him again.

It was very peaceful continent on my side. 
There were no wars, until I create one, No maybe two.

Somehow in Modern era everyone in my continent tried to convince me to join a war against Venice. I declined them all but was interested in funding a proxy war.
**I bribed Korea and Austria, Venice's border to declare war against it and pretend to be innocent.** (rather cheap)

Several turns later, **Venice who use to have Declaration of Friendship with me seemed to find out and suddenly *denounced* me**.

He was right to do so but I wonder how he found out about my scheming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Gods & Kings expansion introduced the concept of "Sharing Intrigue" which allows the AI and you to share bits of information you gather about each other's plans.  It's certainly possible that Venice somehow got word of your plot and that was the source of the denunciation.  When you're talking to them, you can hover over the word that describes their attitude toward you (ie, "Guarded") to see reasons why they think you are a good or bad person.

There's another factor here, though, and that's that the AI will become increasingly suspicious of you as you close in on victory.  If you're in the Modern era, chances are good that you're working towards victory at this point.  If *any* AI figures this out, they are likely to become aggressive towards you.

Comment: I'm not really understand how "Sharing Intrigue" actually works to trigger.

Comment: [this thread seems to hint that it's not "Sharing Intrigue"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74372/under-what-condition-does-the-ai-share-an-intrigue-with-you).

Comment: @Thebluefish I can guess only friend would share these intel. But what event actually trigger to let you or AI decide whether or not to share it.

Comment: @Thebluefish, it's possible that someone friendly to the Venetians was spying on dondonchi and learned of the war plot, and shared the intrigue.  It's unlikely that Korea or Austria would share it, from what I understand.

Comment: Did not think about that :p Certaintly explains a lot with my games now that I understand how it could be used.

Comment: @agent86 that explanation seems legit, will take that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it was intrigue as it seems like just a minor way to earn a diplomacy bonus and nothing more. However, hovering over the attitude description is indeed the way to find out what happened.

If you've declared friendships with the rivals that attacked Venice, it would sour Venice's attitude toward you. Since you cannot denounce someone while at war with them, you may have simply been the first casualty. Once the war is over Venice will likely denounce the others as well.

And as agent68 pointed out, it may just be that Venice thinks you are close to winning the game.